# January 2018 Patch Tuesday for Server 2008 R2 and Server 2016 no downloads this month

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2016

Last week we installed the out-of-band patches for our Server 2016 boxes.

Currently there are no patches, other than the monthly Malicious Software Removal Tool, available to any servers...

I read that Windows Defender must set a registry key to allow future updates. For both 2008 R2 and 2016 boxes Defender is up to date. It seems odd that by Wednesday there aren't any security patches showing up yet... Did I miss something, or do I need manually set the registry key?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would appear that 'Windows Defender' is rather ambiguous - Windows Defender with Server 2016 is classed as AV and Windows Defender with Server 2008 R2 is just malware. The former sets the correct registry entry and the latter doesn't.

It also would appear that everything for Patch Tuesday was released last week for Server 2016 and this week for Server 2008 R2

After adding the registry key for Server 2008 R2

```
Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"Subkey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\QualityCompat"

Value Name="cadca5fe-87d3-4b96-b7fb-a231484277cc"

Type="REG_DWORD”

Data="0x00000000”
```

and checking for updates the latest patches appeared for our Server 2008 R2 boxes...

Hope the rest of the year will not be so messy!